# is it possible to add different sized section footers to different sections of the same uicollectionview

Tags: uicollectionview, footer

I have a `uicollectionview` that contains 2 sections and I want to add a different sized footer to each section.From the IB i saw I can add only one footer and header per collection.

Is it possible maybe by code if I'll register 2 different footers? Or maybe change the size of the footer in run time for each section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.. It is possible.. You have two option

**option 1 : Register different footer views**

Register footer view through code by using different reuse identifiers

```
    registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:
```

Then

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
NSString *identifier = nil;
if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter]) {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        identifier = @"footerViewOne";
    }
    else{
        identifier = @"footerViewTwo";
    }

}
UICollectionReusableView *supplementaryView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


return supplementaryView;
}
```

**Option 2 : Simply change the size of the footer view**

For that use **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** method

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(PSUICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section==0) {
    return  CGSizeMake(500, 50);
  }
  else
  {
    return CGSizeMake(200, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: cool, thank you very much. I used the second solution (in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout) and it works great !